# Accessing a DbContext dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have an application used to display location data to a user. This data can come from multiple sources (e.g. a WebApi or a LocalDatabase). Therefore I have a repository which manages all the data from these sources.
Each repository implements the following interface

```
interface IRepository<TKey, TValue> : IDiscoverable, ILocalizable
{
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> FindAll();

    TValue Find(TKey identifier);

    // Additional methods left out.
}
```

A concrete implementation (in this case for a WebApi request) then creates a request which gets executed by a ServiceClient. This service client returns a response to the Repository which passes said response to a converter that converts the data into a format used by the application.

Now my problem is the Request part. Not for the WebApi, but for database requests.
I currently have one DbContext for the Locations database, but more will follow when the application gets extended. And herein lies the crux: Writing a ServiceClient for Api requests is easy, since I only have to query a webpage and fetch the JSON. The URL can therefore be built by joining multiple strings. So a Request can look like this:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    /// <summary>Gets the resource path.</summary>
    string Resource { get; }

    /// <summary>Gets the request parameters.</summary>
    /// <returns>A collection of parameters.</returns>
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetParameters();

    /// <summary>Gets additional path segments for the targeted resource.</summary>
    /// <returns>A collection of path segments.</returns>
    IEnumerable<string> GetPathSegments();
}
```

How can I achieve a similar approach with multiple DbContext?

I understand that I have to pass the instance of the DbContext I want to query to the service manager. But how can I query the DbSet properties without writing a Service manager for each DbContext?

Is this eve possible, or would I have to scrap my design altogether?

---

Here are some additional information, This is my current repository implementation. I commented out the code used to query a web api. But I'd like my database querying code to look almost the same.
To clarify: explicit interface implementation is the method the rest of the program calls to get the data. The user is able to switch out the type of repository, thus giving the ability to choose from different data sources.
Inside the method I'll generate a request. If the data source is a web api the request holds information to build an URL to the api endpoint (the Url is built and queried by the `ServiceClient`). The `ServiceClient` then returns a response implementing the `IResponse` interface (see below). The response then is passed to a converter which converts the response to POCOs used by the rest of the application.

What I want to do: Build a request class that allows me to dynamically select the `DbContext` used to access the database. For that I need a way to pass the `DbContext` inside the Request, so the `ServiceClient` can use it. I further need to pass *which* properties to use so I can get the data, since not every endpoint has the same Properties.

Here is the code I have so fat:

```
public interface IResponse<T> : ILocalizable
{
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the response content.</summary>
    T Content { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/> at which the message originated..</summary>
    DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets a collection of custom response headers.</summary>
    IDictionary<string, string> ExtensionData { get; set; }
}


public interface ILocationRepository : IRepository<Guid, Location>
{
}

public class LocationRepository : ILocationRepository 
{
    private readonly LocationContext context;

    private readonly IConverter<IResponse<ICollection<LocationDataContract>>, IDictionary<Guid, Location>> responseConverter;


    public LocationRepository()
    {
        this.context = new LocationContext();

        var locationConverter = new LocationConverter();

        this.responseConverter = new DictionaryResponseConverter<LocationDataContract, Guid, Location>(locationConverter, location => location.Id);
    }

    IDictionary<Guid, Location> IRepository<Guid, Location>.FindAll()
    {
        // This is how the request against a web api looks like.
        // This works without a doubt and totally flawless.
        // IItemRepository self = this;
        // var request = new ItemDetailsRequest
        // {
        //     Identifier = identifier.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), 
        //     Culture = self.Culture
        // };
        // var response = this.serviceClient.Send<ItemDataContract>(request);

        var locations = this.context.Locations.ToList();
        var cityDetails = this.context.CityDetails.ToList();
        var planetDetails = this.context.PlanetDetails.ToList();
        var systemDetails = this.context.SystemDetails.ToList();


        IEnumerable<LocationsDetails> details = cityDetails.Cast<LocationsDetails>().Concat(planetDetails).Concat(systemDetails).ToList();

        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            location.Details = details.SingleOrDefault(detail => detail.Id == location.Id);
        }

        var response = new Response<ICollection<LocationDataContract>>
                           {
                               Content = locations
                           };

        var service = new DatabaseServiceClient<LocationContext>();

        return this.responseConverter.Convert(response);
    }

    Location IRepository<Guid, Location>.Find(Guid identifier)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say your design is overly generic. create a type of data and a repository interface which returns that type for a specific set of parameters.

Comment: @Ewan The thing is: The design works flawlessly for data originating from a web based API. I'll update the Question with some more details to make the flow more clear.

Comment: i would be interested to see more, I always think you end up effectively making your own programming language when you get too generic

Comment: I updated it with more code.

Comment: hmm what i don't understand is the need for your request/response pattern below the repository. surely once you get to a concrete repository it already knows its SQL or webAPI there's no need for further abstraction?

Comment: I don't have control how the data gets to me. That is the reason why I have a repository over a DbContext (which by itself is a repository). The WebApi data comes in a different flavour than the Database data. Therefore I need to convert the data. Thus said: I will get different DbContext in the future (e.g. Characters) and while I can reuse the WebApi approach very well, this is not possible with the current Database approach. So I need to abstract it or I'll end up getting at least three Repositories with almost identical code. And I do not want that.

Comment: sorry, still don't fully get it. it sounds like you have a complex senario, but surely you can turn an sql query into a set of strings? the db could indicate the context?

Comment: I would rather not query with SQL directly. 1. We are currently running SQLServer but are thinking of switching to SQLite and that would mean a potential massive rewrite since both use slightly different query sintax. 2. No compile time checking. Therefore I'd rather use LINQ and that is my problem.

Comment: I cant help but think that your problem is of your own making. just write a repository that connects direct via sqlclient and be done with it. if you switch write a new repository for sql lite.